# Unable to use environment variables in TCL (Linux/Unix)

Tags: shell, tcl

I'm having difficulties trying to use environment variables in TCL.

So I have a shell script which exports a bunch of environment variables so that my TCL scripts can use them later on.

**set_vars.sh** has the following code in it:

`export TEST_ENV_VAR=Test`

and the following works:

> % puts $env(TEST_ENV_VAR)
>
> Test

BUT once I place the environment variable in a operator or in quotes, nothing is returned.

> % puts "$env(TEST_ENV_VAR) is in TEST_ENV_VAR"
>
> is in TEST_ENV_VAR

Anyone know what the issue could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems the second time around, you did not run your **set_vars.sh** script. I tried your examples and they work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

There must be something you're not showing us:

```
$ export TEST_ENV_VAR=Test
$ tclsh
% puts $env(TEST_ENV_VAR)
Test
% puts "$env(TEST_ENV_VAR) is in TEST_ENV_VAR"
Test is in TEST_ENV_VAR
```

Note that `env` is a **global** variable, so if you're using it in a procedure, you must declare it as `global`

```
$ tclsh
% proc show_env1 {varname} {
    puts "does not work: $env($varname)"
}
% show_env1 TEST_ENV_VAR
can't read "env(TEST_ENV_VAR)": no such variable
% proc show_env2 {varname} {
    global env
    puts "works: $env($varname)"
}
% show_env2 TEST_ENV_VAR
works: Test
% proc show_env3 {varname} {
    puts "also works: $::env($varname)"
}
% show_env3 TEST_ENV_VAR
also works: Test
```